# Issue populating label from date picker and calculating

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have been working on this for a little while today and I am stumped. I am attempting to select a date using a date picker and take that date, populate a label with it and also take input from the user to add days to the selected date. The date picker works fine, I however cannot get the date to populate the label and I am not sure how to calculate say 6 days in advance with that date. The code to add the days is straight forward, I am not sure how to take the date and make it calculable.

Here is what I have so far:

**View**

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form id="calendarForm" action="~/Views/Calendar/Calendar.cshtml" method="post">
    <h2>Calendar Application</h2>
    <p>This application will display a the specified number of days <br /> the user inputs on a calendar.</p>
    <br />
    <h2>Select A Date</h2>

    @model VanickCalendarApp.Models.Calendar

    <!-- Date picker visible -->
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="Date" />
    </p>

    <!-- Takes the date from the picker and calculates it new date on button click-->
    <script>

        $('button').click(function () {
            var datePickerSelected = $("#Date").datepicker("getDate");
            var endDate = new Date();
            var selDate = $('#Date').val();
            var DaysToBeAdded = addDaysEntered;
            endDate = (selDate + DaysToBeAdded);
        });

    </script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate Days", "Calendar", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <h2>Enter The Number Of Days To Display</h2>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DaysToBeViewed)

        <label id="dateSelected">"Date"</label>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="daysAdded()" />
    }


        <!-- Create the date picker script -->
        <script>

        $(function () {
        $('#Date').datepicker();

    });

    </script>

    <!-- Creates an alert to test the values for debuging -->
     <script>
         document.getElementById('dateSelected').valueOf = dateSelected
         alert.valueOf("Date");

     </script>

</form>
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using VanickCalendarApp.Models;


namespace VanickCalendarApp.Controllers
{
    public class CalendarController : Controller
    {

        public string CalculateDays(string Date)
        {
            var oneDAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

             return Date;
        }
        //
        // GET: /Calendar/

        public ActionResult Calendar()
        {


            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Calendar/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Calendar/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Calendar/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Calendar/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Calendar/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Calendar/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Calendar/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace VanickCalendarApp.Models
{
    public class Calendar
    {
        //[DataType(DataType.Date)]

        public string date { get; set; }
        public int DaysToBeViewed { get; set; }
        public DateTime newDate { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, so is the problem that the date is not calculating correctly? So when you add '6' days the result is incorrect?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your code.  For example, you init the datepicker in two different places and have a button click event but no button on the form.  Also var DaysToBeAdded = addDaysEntered; where is addDaysEntered defined?

Comment: The date picker displays the selected date and I am unable to take that date and add days to it to display a new date.

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us - The date picker following <!-- Create the date picker script --> is there because if I only have the previous init, the date picker does not render correctly.

Comment: That might be because in document.ready, the selector ("#date") is in lower case, and the id is uppercase.

Comment: I fixed that but I am still not getting the value of the date from the picker.

Comment: You're calling getDate in multiple places and we don't know which one you're talking about because your page is full of dead code that no one wants to wade through.  If you're talking about var datePickerSelected = $("#Date").datepicker("getDate");, this is outside of a function and being executed immediately, before the user ever selects a date.

Comment: Sorry for the poor code, I am really new to C# / JavaScript. Where does that line go?

Comment: Cleaned up the VIEW code